# Mostrar el primer texto del ViewPager en Android Studio obtenido de un array

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

estoy realizando un proyecto que consiste en lo siguiente:
Cuando se inicia la aplicación se muestra un listado de paises, el código de esa actividad...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;

    Arrays arrays;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        arrays = new Arrays();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrays.getPaises());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int posicion, long id) {                  
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScreenSlidePagerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("posicion", posicion);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

el xml <<--activity_main-->>

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Los paises los obtengo de una clase llamada Array que me va a dar el array de paises.

```
public class Arrays {

    private String[] paises = { "Argentina", "Chile", "Paraguay", "Bolivia",
            "Peru", "Ecuador", "Brasil", "Colombia", "Venezuela", "Uruguay" };
    private String[] habitantes = { "40000000", "17000000", "6500000",
            "10000000", "30000000", "14000000", "183000000", "44000000",
            "29000000", "3500000" };

    public String [] getPaises(){
        return paises;
    }

    public String [] getHabitantes(){
        return habitantes;
    }
}
```

Bien hasta ahí. Ahora cuando presiono en uno de esos paises la app va a una actividad que es un ViewPager, el objetivo es que cuando presione un país en el listview vaya al activity del viewpager mostrando ese país y que permita desplazar el dedo a la izquierda o a la derecha mostrando los demas paises del lisview (normalmente eso es lo que hace un viewpager), aqui esta esa actividad.

El pagerfragment:

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

el xml del fragment <<-fragment_screen_slide_page--->>:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="texto prueba" />
</ScrollView>
```

El activity que tiene el pager:

```
public class ScreenSlidePagerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The number of pages (wizard steps) to show in this demo.
     */
    private static int NUM_PAGES = 0;

    /**
     * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally to access previous
     * and next wizard steps.
     */
    private ViewPager mPager;

    /**
     * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
     */
    private ScreenSlidePagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    int posicion;

    Arrays arrays;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);

        //esto es para poder llamar al array de paises
        arrays = new Arrays();

        //El numero de paginas va a ser igual a la cantidad de paises
        NUM_PAGES = arrays.getPaises().length;


        //obtengo la posicion del pais que presione en el listview
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        posicion = bundle.getInt("posicion");

        // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

        //el pager va aempezar en la posicion del pais que seleccione
        mPager.setCurrentItem(posicion);

        mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                try {

                    TextView texto = (TextView) mPagerAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(mPager.getCurrentItem()).getView().findViewById(R.id.t1);
                    texto.setText(arrays.getPaises()[position]);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                }

                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                //invalidateOptionsMenu();

                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                //invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    /**
     * A simple pager adapter that represents 5 ScreenSlidePageFragment objects, in
     * sequence.
     */
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        //por mi
        SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
        }

        //por mi
        public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
            return registeredFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
            registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
            return fragment;
        }
    }

}
```

el xml que tiene el pager <<--activity_screen_slide-->>:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Ahora, lo que pasa es que en la propiedad onPageSelected() que esta dentro del  mPager.addOnPageChangeListener() yo logro que al deplazar el dedo se muestren correctamente los paises, pero cuando yo voy desde la actividad del lisview hasta la actividad del pager ese primer país que tiene que salir no sale, eso se queda en blanco, es solo despues de que desplazo el dedo hacia la derecha o hacia la izquierda que se muestra el país que biene a continuación o el anterior respectivamente...Como puedo solucionar eso. Garcias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que le seteas el position al pager antes de agregarle el OnPageChangeListener. Te recomiendo que pongas el setPosition en el onResume y para estar mas seguro tambien le podes agregar un postDelayed()

```
int posicion = 0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   posicion = bundle.getInt("posicion");
}

protected void onResume(){
    //De esta forma te aseguras que el pager este creado y con el listener seteado
    mPager.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
          mPager.setCurrentItem(posicion);
       }
    }, 100);
}    

//Esto va en la implementacion del OnPageChangeListener
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int i) {
   position = i;//actializo la posicion
}
```

Edito la respuesta para darte un ejemplo de codigo de lo que te decia en el comentario.

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
   SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();
   Array<String> paises = new Array();

   public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,Array<String> paises) {
      super(fm);
      this.paises = paises;
   }

   @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
      fragment.setPais(paise.get(position));
      return fragment;
   }

   public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
      return registeredFragments.get(position);
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
      return paises.count;
   }

   @Override
   public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position){
      Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
      registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
      return fragment;
   }
}
```

Imagino que con esto quedara mas claro y podras hacerlo andar correctamente.

Comment: Hola @Erick Silva garcias, me funciono lo que me dijisteis, pero me gustaria que al desplazar el dedo por la pantalla salga la vista previa del pais que viene a continuación,  Por ejemplo si presionao chile, el próximo pais que viene es paraguay pero no se ve el texto de paraguay hasta que no sulto el dedo y he visto ejemplos en que se ve una vista previa del próximo texto antes de soltar el dedo.

Comment: Para eso vas a necesitar tres cosas.
Primero al ScreenSlidePageFragment agregale un metodo setText(String pais) para que ponga el texto en el TextView.
Segundo al PagerAdapter pasale el Array con los paises, puede ser en el constructor o con un set.
Tercero en el getItem() del adapter usando el position conseguis el pais que corresponda del array de paises y se lo pasas a la nueva instancia de ScreenSlidePageFragment con el seter que te mencione antes.
De esta forma ya no necesitarias el onPageChanged. Ademas que esta forma te va a servir siempre que uses Adapters.

Comment: Lo q pasa es que no entiendo como pasar el array de paises al PagerAdapter, eso es lo que queria hacer al principio pero no se como enviar ese array al ScreenSlidePageFragment, no se como es que funciona esa parte. Te agradaceria mucho un ejemplo en código -Erick Silva

Comment: gracias man, ya me funciona como queria.